# What does the message 'This file contains potentially unsafe ...' mean and how serious is it?

Tags: dynamic, warning-messages, security

I had some *Mathematica* files on over which recently I have faced to this message:

[image: This file contains potentially unsafe dynamic content. More Details >>]

However, after searching, I have seen some blogs in Mathematica SE or in somewhere else about that, but I could not finally briefly conclude that **whether**, my files, because of their saving local disk positions (for example, pc Desktop) *potentialy* or *probably* maybe be on exposure to attacks or something else caused by viruses or spies (and this possibility will be removed by replacement of the files, or applying bit changes); **or not** and surely and definitely, they are being attacked or had been attacked.

Comment: From where did you download these files?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29364, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38799

Comment: @guess who it is, They are my own files. I have not downloaded from any where. I have written them myself however they are not so important!

Comment: @Michael E2, Thanks for your link, I had seen that previously. But I did not see any dangerous,code, same as that on this link on my computer to run it. I have seen this message over on my own file.

Comment: Yes, I read it. But I did not expect that I see this massage on my own code, my interpretation, of that  was: another files are active and I was worried about that. Although, my question is remained that why after one month from putting my files on untrusted path, mathematica warned me.

Comment: @mr.0093 This error prompts when you open such file, not when you are saving them.

Comment: What this message means: Any notebook containing Dynamic stuff is potentially dangerous.  That's because when you open such a notebook, code might be automatically run without user interaction.  Someone could send you a notebook that will automatically delete all files from your hard drive when you open it.  Mathematica does not know who created a notebook, so it displays the warning whether it's your notebook or a foreign one that you opened.  There's a the "trusted path" functionality (see answer) to ameliorate this inconvenience.

Comment: @Kuba, and@Szabolcs, Actually, As long as I had changed my codes and had written them, I have saved all of them on my Desktop. Yesterday, I just opened the last one (previously myself changed), when I saw the message, I did not run that and I have searched what happened.

Comment: Reminds me of Dodgeball. "I thought those were just warnings!"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Presumably your Notebooks are not being saved in a Trusted Path.  Start by reading the tutorial [Notebook Security](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NotebookSecurity.html), and note:

- If the notebook's directory is trusted, the notebook will be allowed
  to automatically perform dynamic evaluations without alerting the
  user.
- If the notebook's directory is untrusted, the user will be alerted
  upon any attempt by the notebook to perform dynamic evaluations.
- By default, the TrustedPath option value contains [`$InstallationDirectory`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$InstallationDirectory.html), [`$BaseDirectory`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$BaseDirectory.html), and [`$UserBaseDirectory`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$UserBaseDirectory.html) so that Wolfram System installation files and additional installed applications will be able to display dynamic content without alerting the user.

The tutorial also covers how to add a directory to this path.  Run this code and click the button produced:

```
Button["Edit TrustedPath...", 
  FEPrivate`OptionDialog[$FrontEnd, 
    {"NotebookSecurityOptions", "TrustedPath"}], 
  Appearance -> {Automatic, "DialogBox"},
  Evaluator -> Automatic, Method -> "Preemptive"]
```

Or see: [How to add a trusted path in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28921/121)