# Potentially unsafe dynamic content banner: how to remove it?

Tags: notebooks

Everytime I open one of my notebook the following banner appears at the top of the notebook

[image]

How can I remove it?

Comment: You’ll need to add the notebook’s path to a set of trusted paths. Search that on the site.

Comment: @b3m2a1 done thank you.

Comment: If somebody has this problem, the solution is in this answer: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28928/8822